# How to load browser.esm.js modules in Nuxt 2?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, es6-modules

I am getting the following errors when trying to import `@thirdweb-dev/wallets` module in a Nuxt 2 project:

```
 ERROR  in ./node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/sdk/dist/marketplace-auction-3488e43b.browser.esm.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (102:16)                      friendly-errors 17:02:03
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

How can I configure a loader for this module to make it work?